# Can I finish side quests after completing the main story?

Tags: dying-light

I'm three-quarters through the main story, and am wondering if I complete it will I still be able to finish the side quests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, according to users in threads like [this one](https://steamcommunity.com/app/239140/discussions/0/405692224228264212/), completing the game will return you to a "pre-completed" state in which you are able to go complete whatever side quests you'd like.

> It's not a point of no return, you can still play after the Finale, it just reverts you to a 'pre-Finale' state (similar to the base game)
>
> oh ok, then the side missions will still be available to do?
>
> In my experience, yes.

[Here](https://www.playstationtrophies.org/forum/dying-light/258119-side-quests-missable.html)'s another thread discussing this:

> Can I finish the story mode first then do the side quests after?
>
> Nothing is missable. Once you finish the story missions it sticks you back in free roam.